# Why does vanilla HTML/JS (and React) use camelCase for stylings, while CSS does not?

Tags: javascript, html, css, conventions

Different pieces of technology regarding styling require different conventions for naming certain properties, mainly camelCase vs. hyphenated-style

Setting styles directly on an HTML DOM Node via JS - element.style.paddingTop = "12px";

Setting styles inline in React - < Component style={{paddingTop: "12px"}} />

Setting it in a .CSS file - .selector {padding-top: 12px}

What is the underlying reason for the different rules?  I don't see why this is better than all of HTML/CSS/JS using camelCase, or all of it using hyphenated-style.

Comment: We are writing css in js Js commonly use camel case

Comment: Styleguide, buddy.

Comment: Because `padding-top` is not a valid property name, unless you're using it with bracket notation.

Comment: Actually it"s only JS using camel-case, HTML uses hyphen mode.

Comment: In JS, `-` is an arithmetic operator, and `element.style.padding-top` would be parsed as `(element.style.padding) - top`. Hence the camelCase workaround.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, *kebab-case* doesn't fit because of syntax rule. `-` is not allowed in identifier so `padding-top` is not valid for variable or property name.

In CSS, *camelCase* is not a good practice because CSS is case-insensitive. `className` and `classname` is the same identifier for CSS.